# How to create separate admin panel for my customer in zencart

Tags: zen-cart

How to create separate admin panel for my customer in zen cart with some privilege?

Comment: not sure what you mean, can you clarify your question? Zencart as of the version 1.5.1 already has some admin profiles features built in

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Zen Cart has an "Admin Access Management" choice in the main admin menu toolbar. Simply set up a new profile, assign whichever permissions you desire to that profile, and then create an admin user to use that profile. That user will then see only the choices you've granted them.